# golang enum support in swagger codegen

Tags: go, swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen

I am not able to generate the enum with swagger codegen for golang. What modification needs to be done in go model.mustache and GoClientCodegen.java ?

I tried this in mustache  :

```
{{>partial_header}}
package {{packageName}}
{{#models}}{{#imports}}
import ({{/imports}}{{#imports}}
"{{import}}"{{/imports}}{{#imports}}
)
{{/imports}}{{#model}}{{#description}}
// {{{description}}}{{/description}}
type {{classname}} struct {
{{#vars}}{{#description}}
// {{{description}}}{{/description}}
{{name}} {{{datatype}}} `json:"{{baseName}},omitempty"`
{{/vars}}
}
{{#enum}}
type enum string
const (
"COMPLETE"
"INCOMPLETE"
)
{{/enum}}
{{/model}}{{/models}}
```

GoClientCodegen.java is same. What needs to be modified in the java file and the mustache file ?

Comment: Please open an "issue" in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that we can look into the issue with a spec you provided.

Comment: Have posted in swagger-codegen as new issue.. I am new and not able to figure out how can I generate enum with the same model.mustache as I dont see the support for the same in the mustache file. I can see that DefaultCodegen has the option but I m not able to understand it for reusing. I feel that something must be added within mustache file to support the same and GoClientCodegen as well needs to be modified.